# Base having open compact members

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

What are some examples of topological spaces where open compact subsets form base for the topology? Where can I get discussion on such spaces?

For example, every compact [zero-dimensional space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-dimensional_space) has this property, but there might be some other spaces with such base.

Comment: Why is this closed? It's a completely standard question. I wrote an answer answering all of it and now I cannot publish the answer. The spaces in question are important, as they appear in Stone duality theorems. I am forced to publish my answer in the comments.

Comment: Recall that a space is **$0$-dimensional** iff it has a base consisting of clopens (closed and open).

Let us first think about Hausdorff spaces. If $X$ is Hausdorff and has a base $\mathcal{B}$ of compact opens, then the basic opens are also closed (because in a Hausdorff space a compact set is closed), therefore it is $0$-dimensional. Moreover, it is locally compact since every point has an arbitrarily small compact neighborhood (namely a basic one).

Comment: Conversely, suppose $X$ is Hausdorff, locally compact and $0$-dimensional. We claim that the compact open sets form a basis. For this purpose, consider any open set $U$ and a point $x \in U$. It suffices to find a compact open $V$ such that $x \in V \subseteq U$. Because $X$ is locally compact, there is a compact neighborhood $K$ such that $x \in K \subseteq U$. Because $X$ is $0$-dimensional, there is a clopen neighborhood $V$ such that $x \in V \subseteq K$. But $V$ is actually compact, as it is a closed subset of a compact set $K$. We are done. We proved:

Comment: **Theorem:** A Hausdorff space has a base of compact open sets if, and only if, it is $0$-dimensional and locally compact.

Comment: Such spaces abound. For example, the Cantor space, the interval topology on an ordinal $\alpha$, the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{N}$ (which is the interval topology on $\omega + 1$), etc.

Comment: How about non-Hausdorff spaces? (Contrary to the popular opinion arising from how topology is taught, these can be perfectly "intuitive" as well.) Here I do not see an immediate characterization, but examples are easy enough to come by. For instance, take and poset $(P, {\leq})$ and consider the topology on $P$ consisting of *upper* sets (a set $L \subseteq P$ is upper if $x \in L$ and $x \leq y$ implies $y \in L$). The opens of the form ${\uparrow}x = \{y \in P \mid x \leq y\}$ form a basis, and they are compact because as soon as you cover $x$ you've covered ${\uparrow}x$.

Comment: Good post @AndrejBauer.  I would've loved to +1 that as a proper answer.

Comment: @AndrejBauer wow! Any reference suggestion ?

Comment: Sure, if you look up anything regarding Stone duality and genralized Boolean algebras, you'll get plenty.

Comment: You should flag the question as "in need of moderator intervention" and request that it be re-opened.

Comment: @AndrejBauer done :-)

Comment: @KajHansen In that case, voting to reopen the question would be a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Perhaps if you could edit the question to add a few words explaining why the question can be considered interesting, that might improve the chance of getting reopened. I have tried to find some support for reopening the post [also elsewhere](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2165/2017/10/1) - we will see how this turns out in the end. (Needless to say, I am not that surprised that question containing two sentences with no motivation at all got closed.)

Comment: Nah, if the people who have the power to re-open can't tell this is a legit question, epsecially after reading the comments that are already there, let it all go down the drain.

Comment: @AndrejBauer The question is reopened now - in case you are still interested in posting an answer. To make things easier for you, the text of comments is copied below in a CW answer, which can be easy to copy-and-past than from comments. (Feel free to ping me on the answer to let me know that it can be deleted after you post you answer - the CW answer is then no longer needed.)

Comment: @AndrejBauer In case you are interested to know, your pair of comments above are an excellent motivation to **avoid reopening** this. One cannot deliberately neglect the rules of the site (which say questions without context should be avoided) and then act surprised when other people act according to said rules, can one?

Comment: Sure. But the mods seem a bit trigger happy. Anyone with decent knowledge of general topology will recognize the relevance of the question and ask for it to be amended. But apparently not those who wield power around here. A mistake was made so fix it instead of placing further bureaucratic burden on those who made no mistake. So don't go all Wikipedia admin on us, the contributors. Threatening with rules will just make people walk away. Look at Wikipedia.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Sorry but I fail to read this as "further bureaucratic burden", rather as trying to keep a minimal level of decency to the site (a difficult task, I know). (Unrelated: Please use @ when needed.)

Comment: @AndrejBauer I'll just point out that "But the mods seem a bit trigger happy" doesn't make much sense here. According to the [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2191926/timeline), there has been no [moderator](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) who has voted to close this question.

Comment: Also, my two cents on the issue: while you may feel threatened by the rules, I feel a small amount amount of offense when I find this site being used (and abused) in ways that allow people get free homework service. Detrimental to my pride in this site and all...

Comment: I accept the points made by @Did. I apologize for being in such a bad mood. If it's worth anything, it was because a good friend of mine died (and happened to be also be a first-rate mathematician).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: you think this was homework?

Comment: @AndrejBauer That's sad, I'm very sorry for you.

Comment: No, I do not believe this is homework. But I believe it is likely the deepest explanation for the past closure of this question. If we didn't have such questions, many users wouldn't close questions such as these, at least, in my honest opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [compact subspaces of Hausdorff topological spaces are closed](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Compact_Subspace_of_Hausdorff_Space_is_Closed).  Therefore, we need to either find non-Hausdorff spaces (harder since these are less intuitive) with this property, or find Hausdorff spaces with a base whose members are without boundary (hence clopen) as well as compact.

One possibility of the latter would be the [discrete topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space#Definitions) on any set.  This has as a base singleton sets which are both open and compact.

For non-Hausdorff examples, we can take any topology on any finite set (all finite subspaces of a topological space are compact).  The difficult task is finding infinite non-Hausdorff spaces with this property.

Comment: Does there exist examples of infinite non hausdroff space with this property?

Comment: I have no idea.  =/

Comment: @Jave the cofinite topology on an infinite set has your property, and is not Hausdorff

Answer (score 1):

This is only a temporary answer - to be deleted soon. It was posted to make copy-pasting of the text posted in the comments easier.

The spaces in question are important, as they appear in Stone duality theorems. I am forced to publish my answer in the comments. -- [Andrej Bauer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191926/base-having-open-compact-members#comment4509930_2191926)

Recall that a space is **$0$-dimensional** iff it has a base consisting of clopens (closed and open).  Let us first think about Hausdorff spaces. If $X$ is Hausdorff and has a base $\mathcal{B}$ of compact opens, then the basic opens are also closed (because in a Hausdorff space a compact set is closed), therefore it is $0$-dimensional. Moreover, it is locally compact since every point has an arbitrarily small compact neighborhood (namely a basic one). -- [Andrej Bauer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191926/base-having-open-compact-members#comment4509934_2191926)

Conversely, suppose $X$ is Hausdorff, locally compact and $0$-dimensional. We claim that the compact open sets form a basis. For this purpose, consider any open set $U$ and a point $x \in U$. It suffices to find a compact open $V$ such that $x \in V \subseteq U$. Because $X$ is locally compact, there is a compact neighborhood $K$ such that $x \in K \subseteq U$. Because $X$ is $0$-dimensional, there is a clopen neighborhood $V$ such that $x \in V \subseteq K$. But $V$ is actually compact, as it is a closed subset of a compact set $K$. We are done. We proved: -- [Andrej Bauer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191926/base-having-open-compact-members#comment4509935_2191926)

**Theorem:** A Hausdorff space has a base of compact open sets if, and only if, it is $0$-dimensional and locally compact. -- [Andrej Bauer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191926/base-having-open-compact-members#comment4509936_2191926)

Such spaces abound. For example, the Cantor space, the interval topology on an ordinal $\alpha$, the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{N}$ (which is the interval topology on $\omega + 1$), etc. -- [Andrej Bauer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191926/base-having-open-compact-members#comment4509937_2191926)

How about non-Hausdorff spaces? (Contrary to the popular opinion arising from how topology is taught, these can be perfectly "intuitive" as well.) Here I do not see an immediate characterization, but examples are easy enough to come by. For instance, take and poset $(P, {\leq})$ and consider the topology on $P$ consisting of *upper* sets (a set $L \subseteq P$ is upper if $x \in L$ and $x \leq y$ implies $y \in L$). The opens of the form ${\uparrow}x = \{y \in P \mid x \leq y\}$ form a basis, and they are compact because as soon as you cover $x$ you've covered ${\uparrow}x$. -- [Andrej Bauer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191926/base-having-open-compact-members#comment4509938_2191926)

Good post @AndrejBauer.  I would've loved to +1 that as a proper answer. -- [Kaj Hansen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191926/base-having-open-compact-members#comment4509964_2191926)

@AndrejBauer wow! Any reference suggestion ? -- [Jave](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191926/base-having-open-compact-members#comment4509973_2191926)

Sure, if you look up anything regarding Stone duality and generalized Boolean algebras, you'll get plenty. -- [Andrej Bauer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191926/base-having-open-compact-members#comment4509978_2191926)